# Regular Expression \d matches with multiple numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I was looking at a C# Regex tutorial which stated that "\d" matches a single digit 0 to 9.

However when I ran the following program.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "45";
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"(\d)");

        if( myRegex.IsMatch(s))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Matched");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Not Matched");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The console printed out "Matched".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"^\d$");
```

Comment: You have not whitespace in the pattern, so why that flag..?

Comment: The `{1}` has no effect, either.  Why did you add that?

Answer (score 10):

Well yeah, it finds the `4`, because regular expression matches do not have to cover the full input string. If you want to make sure that your string is **only** a single digit, include anchors, that mark the beginning and end of the string:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"^(\d)$");
```

Now the match has to start at the beginning of the string (marked by `^`) and has to end at the end of the string (marked by `$`). Thus, only single-digit inputs will be allowed. Omitting this allows the regular expression to match any substring of your input.